# GoogleSignIn - How to refresh the access token? Can't find anything on it in the docs

Tags: android, google-signin

I've successfully integrated `GoogleSignIn` into my Android app, but after 1 hour, the access token expires. How do I refresh the token?

I've checked out the entire docs for `GoogleSignIn` but there's nothing on refreshing the `accessToken`

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

I've also tried searching for a method that has something like ".refreshAccessToken()"

[image]

How do I refresh the token? Why is there nothing about it in the docs?

Comment: The neatest/most-efficient way to implement this is on a backend server. Do you have access to this? If yes, you can exchange auth code for tokens using the [GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest) class.

Comment: No I don't have access to it. And the user did not implement such an endpoint

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think there's a way to implement this on mobile. If you can, inform the backend guy to implement an endpoint that leverages on my answer below. It'd save you a lot of stress.

Comment: In the meantime, I hope you get a more actionable answer for your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

The approach below works if you have control of the server powering your Android project. I'll use Java to illustrate since your screenshot is in Java.

From the attached image, I can see that you are able to retrieve `GoogleSignInAccount` after authenticating the user. You can get a **server auth code** from this by performing:

```
String authCode = account.getServerAuthCode();
```

You can then send this auth code to your server and exchange it for a refresh token using the [GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest) class. Here's an illustration below:

```
String CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "/path/to/client_secret.json";
String REDIRECT_URI = "" //Leave empty if you don't have a redirect url

GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new FileReader(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE));  
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId(), clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret(), authCode, REDIRECT_URI).execute();
 
String accessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();  
String refreshToken = tokenResponse.getRefreshToken();  
Long expiresInSeconds = tokenResponse.getExpiresInSeconds();
```

Lastly, you can plug the refresh token to your GoogleCredential like below:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()  
          .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())  
          .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())  
          .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)  
          .build();  
 credential.setAccessToken(accessToken);  
 credential.setExpiresInSeconds(expiresInSeconds);  
 credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
```

That's it. You can get more information about this process [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/using-credentials-between-your-server.html).

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution, but I unfortunately don't have access to the code, and the dev won't implement it.